# Webbased MySQL interface better that phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any webbased interface for MySQL better than phpMyAdmin? I use phpMyAdmin a lot but it is becoming a pain, especially it is slow sometimes.

I'd like to have deep export functionality like phpMyAdmin but more design features

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just use a client? They are a lot nicer in my opinion.

I love [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) because it supports a lot of MySQL features (stored procedures) but I used to use HeidiSQL and it was nice as well.

As for web based clients, I haven't got any suggestions unfortunately.

Comment: Because my host won't allow remote clients

Answer (score 4):

Try [DBlite](http://dblite.com). It's has got a nice intuitive interface and gets the work done faster and with fewer clicks than in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Presently the link `dblite.com/` is a website selling cloths.

Answer (score 2):

try checking these out http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/database/

as a client, I recommend EMS Manager, as well as for Posgtres

Comment: Fantastic link, provides a range of web based interfaces for MySQL. Good work. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know about [SqlBuddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/). It has a simpler interface that phpMyAdmin - but pma is much more powerful.

There is also the [VFront](http://www.vfront.org/en/) application. I have not tried it yet - so I cannot comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

As clients, the MySQL Query browser and Administrator are quite good. That has a number of different export facilities that are cool. If it needs to be web though, then you might be best sticking with the slow phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2):

Among non-web clients, I use [Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/). The free version can do everything phpMyAdmin can

Comment: I can't find a free version download in there website there is only a trial version

Comment: Unfortunately they discontinued the free versions. You can still get the last free version someplace else: http://download.cnet.com/Navicat-Lite-for-MySQL/3000-10254_4-10908646.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webdesigneronline.co.uk/10-great-alternatives-to-phpmyadmin

It lists several on here but also lists a few not mentioned like

**Adminer**

I started using Adminer as it comes with free skins and scripts and mods - best of all, it one PHP file that sits on the server, so you can even call it "private_32492834234.php"

Answer (score 0):

as a client I recommend [Toad For Mysql](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/Overview.htm) (it is free)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest [AeroSQL](http://www.burlaca.com/aerosql/), it's an open source (GPL) web based MySql Manager built using PHP and ExtJS library.

There is a demo, video and screenshots available.

Project homepage: http://www.burlaca.com/aerosql/

The key feature of the product is an intuitive management of the database content. The result of SELECTs is displayed in a grid as in traditional desktop applications. The grid is editable: you can update cells and save the changes to the backend database server.

Comment: extjs not downloading

Answer (score 0):

I suggest phpadminer because it is lightweight and has only one php file, but you should continue with slow phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy im using [mywebsql](http://mywebsql.net/) and im very happy with it. You should check it out.