# MySQL database query client

Tags: mysql, sql, openfire

The database that is being used is MySQL database.
I want to install a query browser client. 
I was asked to install openfire.
When I installed it, it does not let me login. It also shows admin login page.
I am very new to this database or the database client.

Can you point to me the openfire mysql database client for querying the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openfire is not a client for viewing databases, it is a instant messaging server that uses a database (like MySQL or its own proprietary file-based db) to store the instant messages sent between its users. (unless there is some other product called openfire)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfire

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need a query browser. so this instant messaging server is not helpful to me.

Comment: I usually use the command line or the tools that come with the database install, but I guess if you didn't install the mysql instance you won't have those tools... I think many folks use phpMyAdmin for what you want. There is a similar question asked here, maybe it will help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449570/webbased-mysql-interface-better-that-phpmyadmin   Good Luck!

Comment: Note, it uses HSQLDB by default (embedded), there is no proprietary file-based db.

Comment: Oops thanks Robin, I didn't realize the default db wasn't homegrown for Openfire. That db is backed by a text file that you can view/edit in a text editor rather than an sql client (as per https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/46922) so that can be handy. But not useful for star1 if his/her openfire installation was installed with MySQl instead of the default db.